# Generate random first name

Tags: r, random, package

Is there a way in R to generate random first names ?

For instance :

```
random_names(5)
[1] "Tristan" "Emile" "Britney" "Alex" "Steeve"
```

If a list already exists somewhere (I need to know where, and how to load it), I could take random indexes in it.

Comment: You can check `randomNames` package

Answer (score 4):

An option is `randomNames`

```
library(randomNames)
library(stringr)
word(randomNames(5, "male", "White"), 1, sep=",")
```

If the `gender` or `ethnicity` is not provided, it selects from the whole list

```
word(randomNames(5), 1, sep=",")
```